# accuracy of tf.metrics.mean_squared_error

Tags: python, tensorflow

For the study needs, I want to check the accuracy of tf.Metrics.mean_squared_error. To my surprise, they are much different. I am seeking for explanations. Here is my experiement brief followed by my sample code:

1) evaluate the trained toy model with the whole training data by tf.Metrics.mean_squared_error; and

2) evaluate again immediately after the step 1, by first collecting the prediction given all "Xs" (or images) of the same whole training data, and then computing the mean squared error with all the ground truth (or labels) of the training data and the prediction.

I have two unproved explanations: (1) float precision loss accumulates and (2) tf.Metrics.mean_square_error applies seemingly moving average in its implementation that brings about inaccuracy.

Any relavent ideas are greatly appreciated! Thanks!

---

```
import tensorflow as tf
from numpy import genfromtxt

tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.INFO)
# (hyper)parameters
batch_size = 200
num_epochs = 1000
steps = 1000
# prepare data
with tf.Session() as sess:
    training_x = sess.run(tf.random_normal([2048, 16], mean=-1, stddev=4, dtype=tf.float64))
    training_y = norm = sess.run(tf.random_normal([2048, 1], mean=-1, stddev=4, dtype=tf.float64))
# input function
_input_fn = lambda _input_path: genfromtxt(_input_path, delimiter=',')
input_training = tf.contrib.learn.io.numpy_input_fn({"input": training_x}, training_y,
                                              batch_size=batch_size, num_epochs=num_epochs)
input_evaluate_train_data = tf.contrib.learn.io.numpy_input_fn({"input": training_x}, training_y)

# remember to give the same column name as used in _input_fn
features = [tf.contrib.layers.real_valued_column('input', dimension=16)]
regressor = tf.contrib.learn.DNNRegressor(feature_columns=features,
                                          hidden_units=[32, 8],
                                          dropout=0.1,
                                          model_dir="testDNNR/result",
                                          optimizer=tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.008),
                                          activation_fn=tf.nn.elu)

# training
regressor.fit(input_fn=input_training, steps=steps)
# testing with training data
eval_metric_ops = {
    "mse": lambda targets, predictions: tf.metrics.mean_squared_error(tf.cast(targets, tf.float64), predictions)
}
ev = regressor.evaluate(input_fn=input_evaluate_train_data, steps=1, metrics=eval_metric_ops)
pred = regressor.predict(input_fn=input_evaluate_train_data, as_iterable=False)
# using my MSE
mse = ((training_y - pred) ** 2).mean()

print ("evaluation result given training data using my MSE: " + str(mse))
print ("evaluation result given training data using the library built-in MSE: " + str(ev))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mismatch comes from how tf.contrib.learn.io.numpy_input_fn works. After some wrapping this function is implemented by https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.3/tensorflow/python/estimator/inputs/numpy_io.py#L45

As you can see, by default, each time it is called it returns a batch of 128 values. When you use it in a call to `regressor.evaluate` you get a different set of 128 values than what you get in when you use it in `regressor.predict`.

There are other related issues. The implementation linked above has `shuffle=True` which means it will pick random 128 elements from your data.

Also, when you do `training_y - pred` the sizes are very different and the tensors get *broadcasted* resulting in many more terms than what you expect.